# jQuery: how to add class to all divs on page except current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, addclass, removeclass

is there a way I can add remove the same class from all DIVs on a page - except for the one I am currently on (clicked on) ?

Background: 
All DIVs on my page have the class "editable" which on click makes the corresponding div editable and shows an inline editor for it. 
While someone is editing a div I want to block all other divs for editing on this page to avoid that multiple editors are opened at the same time.

Can anyone help me with this ?
Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

to [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$('div').not(this).addClass('editable');
```

---

to [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
$('div.editable').not(this).removeClass('editable');
```

---

References

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: thanks, new keyword now add to my jQuery library ..^_^ ..thank you

Comment: @AnisHikmatAbu-hmiad Learning is Must :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".targetClass").click(function() {
      $(".targetClass").not(this).removeClass('classToRemove');
});

//So something like this

$(".editable").click(function() {
      $(".editable").not(this).removeClass('editable');
});
```